# Php - Title in Variable (not working)

Tags: php, tags, title, meta

I'm using include header in all of my php pages and want to extract each page title and description from a variable , this idea is working on php 5.4 at my local pc (wamp) , but on my host where php 5.2.17 is installed , its not showing title of any page ??

page.php:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
$title = "Page title";
?>
```

header.php:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

any help please ??

Comment: You're using `$title` in your header, before you define the variable. try putting the `include` after the definition line.

Comment: you mean include $title = "My page title";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're displaying the value of $title before the assignment.

**page.php:**

```
<?php
   $title = "Page title";
   include("header.php");
?>
```

**header.php:**

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Comment: Why the downvote... this is valid code the solves the OP's problem.

Comment: no luck , still nothing showing but just <title></title> in source code :(

Comment: Make sure you are calling page.php.

This evaluates as desired:

**page.php**

<?php

        $title = "My Page Title";

?>

<html>

        <?php include("head.php"); ?>

        <body>

                <h1>Page Body</h1>

        </body>

</html>


**head.php**

<head>

        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

</head>

Comment: here is my code : header.php <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title ; ?></title>  page.php <?php $title = "My Page Title"; ?> 
<?php include("http://mysite/inc/header.php"); ?>

Comment: Works.
One thing tough, make sure PHP is actually including the header.php and not silently failing. Turn on error reporting by calling error_reporting(E_ALL); as your first instruction in page.php.
Also you are not closing the head tag.
Cheers!

Comment: well header.php is working , i dont know why the same thing is working on my local host with wamp installed but not in my web host :(

Comment: Because of include("mysite/inc/header.php");
Might not always be the right directory.
Try include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysite/inc/header.php");
If you enable the error_reporting you will see it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to echo an undefined variable. The value of `$title` isn't declared but you're trying to echo it in `header.php`. You need to do it like this instead:

**header.php:**

```
<?php
$title ="Page title";
?>
```

**page.php:**

```
<?php
include("header.php");
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable has not been assigned before you try and echo it in your include.

Change page.php to:

```
<?php
$title = "Page title";
include("header.php");
?>
```

(or probably move the variable $title assignment to header.php, making it more organised)

Comment: Done with this , still no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $title = 'title';
    echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
?>
```